# Memory leak using UserControls

Tags: c#, object-oriented, memory-management

I seem to have a memory leak on this method but can't figure it out. This method is called every 10sec by a timer which acts like a refresh.

```
    //Variables

    List<UserControls.userControlAlert> theDataPages = new List<UserControls.userControlAlert>();

    private OleDbConnection mycon;
    private OleDbCommand oleDbCmd;
    private OleDbDataReader dataReader;

    //This method looks for the Alerts in the Data Base and displays the info in a User Control 
    private void ShowData()
    {
        try
        {

            mycon.Open();

            string queriesLabels = "SELECT *FROM MP where State = @stateAccepted OR State = @stateRejected";

            oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand(queriesLabels, mycon);                
            oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@stateAccepted", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Accepted";
            oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@stateRejected", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Rejected";

            dataReader = oleDbCmd.ExecuteReader();              
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {

                    TabPage page = new TabPage("MP "
                                 + (DTL.TabPages.Count + 1).ToString());
                    UserControls.userControlAlert aForm = new UserControls.userControlAlert();
                    aForm.Parent = page;
                    aForm.showReaderRow(dataReader);
                    DTL.TabPages.Add(page);
                    theDataPages.Add(aForm);
                }  
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {              
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            dataReader.Close();
            mycon.Close();
        }
    }
```

Timer (10sec):

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DTL.TabCount > 0)
        {
            theDataPages.Clear();
            DTL.TabPages.Clear();
            ShowData();
        }
        else
        {
            theDataPages.Clear();
            ShowData();
        }
    }
```

If I leave the application open, every 10sec I see an increment on the memory in that process, after some time windows closes the application.

Comment: I've restored the original version of the code since it was modified after receiving an answer.

Comment: @MoralesJosue If I am right in assuming that `tabPage` is really a `System.Windows.Forms.TabPage` and `UserControls.userControlAlert` is some subclass of `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl`, then you need to dispose of those when you clear `theDataPages` and `DTL.TabPages`.

Comment: @DanLyons would it be safe to say that we need more code to determine how bad the leak is? do you feel this is off-topic?

Comment: @Malachi Yes, I think we need some more code to be sure.  I am also inclined to think this question might be better for SO, since it's asking to fix a problem rather than simply asking for a review of code and just happening to have leaks.

Comment: @DanLyons , I tried using this code to dispose the TabPages "for (int i = DTL.TabCount - 1; i > -1; i--)
                {
                    DTL.TabPages[i].Dispose();
                }"
I still have some leaks, I will post the full code in SO, and end this tread.

Comment: @Malachi, found this post, might not be memory leak after all, something else is making the program to close. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020814/memory-leaks-c-sharp]

Answer (score 4):

Your code should make use of `using` statements instead of the `finally` statement of the `try`/`catch`.

It will allow you to get rid of those ugly private variables in exchange for fun scope specific variables in the `using` statements. And no matter what the connections are all closed.  I think that you are leaving open the `OldDbCommand` which might be holding onto the `OleDbConnection` or at the very least just holding the whole command in memory, but when it runs again it creates an entirely new command.

> ```
> private OleDbConnection mycon;
> private OleDbCommand oleDbCmd;
> private OleDbDataReader dataReader;
>
> //This method looks for the Alerts in the Data Base and displays the info in a User Control 
> private void ShowData()
> {
>     try
>     {
>
>         mycon.Open();
>
>         string queriesLabels = "SELECT *FROM MP where State = @stateAccepted OR State = @stateRejected";
>
>         oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand(queriesLabels, mycon);                
>         oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@stateAccepted", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Accepted";
>         oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@stateRejected", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Rejected";
>
>         dataReader = oleDbCmd.ExecuteReader();              
>             while (dataReader.Read())
>             {
>
>                 tabPage page = new tabPage("MP "
>                              + (DTL.TabPages.Count + 1).ToString());
>                 UserControls.userControlAlert aForm = new UserControls.userControlAlert();
>                 aForm.Parent = page;
>                 aForm.showReaderRow(dataReader);
>                 DTL.TabPages.Add(page);
>                 theDataPages.Add(aForm);
>             }  
>     }
>     catch (Exception error)
>     {              
>         MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
>     }
>     finally
>     {
>         dataReader.Close();
>         mycon.Close();
>     }
> }
> ```

Here is what I would do:

```
private void ShowData()
{
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection("connectionString")
        {
            mycon.Open();
            string queriesLabels = "SELECT *FROM MP where State = @stateAccepted OR State = @stateRejected";

            using (OleDbCommand oleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand(queriesLabels, mycon))
            using (oleDbDataReader dataReader = oleDbCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@stateAccepted", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Accepted";
                oleDbCmd.Parameters.Add("@stateRejected", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "Rejected";

                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    tabPage page = new tabPage("MP "
                                + (DTL.TabPages.Count + 1).ToString());
                    UserControls.userControlAlert aForm = new UserControls.userControlAlert();
                    aForm.Parent = page;
                    aForm.showReaderRow(dataReader);
                    DTL.TabPages.Add(page);
                    theDataPages.Add(aForm);
                }  
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {              
        MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
    }
}
```

Your `OleDbCommand` makes use of the `IDisposable` interface, so use it and make sure that it doesn't leak.

Comment: Changed all the statements to "Using" in every part of the project, still having some leaks, I'm pretty sure is in the method I posted since its the only one that the timer is using, and the increment of memory happens every time the timer event triggers. @Malachi, my guess is that it is deleting the tabs but not the object, I'm currently working on a solution on that.

Comment: regardless you should be using `using` statements.

Comment: I will certainly do. @Malachi

Comment: @MoralesJosue If you e.g store the `dataReader` of `aForm.showReaderRow(dataReader);` in a variable of `aForm` it won't get closed.

Comment: @Heslacher so I should be using aForm.Dipose(); inside my timer ?